# Resize Canvas for better resolution

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know there are posts with that question out there and I tried to apply the answers but somehow it doesn't work for me. Long story short: I want to use fullscreen canvas but if I do so, the resolution is really low. That's why I wanted to first draw in a small canvas and then resize. But obviously I'm doing something wrong with my script as it doesn't resize back to fullscreen. Would be absolutely happy for every hint!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <style>
         * { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
         body, html { height:100%; }
         #myCanvas {
         position:absolute;
         width:100;
         height:100;
         }
      </style>
      <script>

         function resize(canvas) {
         // Lookup the size the browser is displaying the canvas.
         var displayWidth  = canvas.clientWidth;
         var displayHeight = canvas.clientHeight;

         // Check if the canvas is not the same size.
         if (canvas.width  != displayWidth ||
         canvas.height != displayHeight) {

         // Make the canvas the same size
         canvas.width  = displayWidth;
         canvas.height = displayHeight;
         }
         }

         function drawFixation() {

         var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
         var centerX = c.width / 2;
         var centerY = c.height / 2;  
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
         ctx.moveTo(centerX-5,centerY);
         ctx.lineTo(centerX+5,centerY);
         ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY+5);
         ctx.lineTo(centerX,centerY-5);
         ctx.fillStyle ="#FFFFFF"
         ctx.lineWidth = 2;
         ctx.stroke();
         }


         function drawArrow(fromx, fromy, tox, toy, colourarrow){
             //variables to be used when creating the arrow
             var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
             var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
             var headlen = 3;

             var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);

             //starting path of the arrow from the start square to the end square and drawing the stroke
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
             ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
             ctx.strokeStyle = colourarrow;
             ctx.lineWidth = 5;
             ctx.stroke();

             //starting a new path from the head of the arrow to one of the sides of the point
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(tox, toy);
             ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));

             //path from the side point of the arrow, to the other side point
             ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/7));

             //path from the side point back to the tip of the arrow, and then again to the opposite side point
             ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
             ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));

             //draws the paths created above
             ctx.strokeStyle = colourarrow;
             ctx.lineWidth = 5;
             ctx.stroke();
             ctx.fillStyle = colourarrow
             ctx.fill();
         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor='black'>
      <canvas  id="myCanvas" oncl></canvas>
      <script>
         var differentcolours = ['#FFA500','#FFFF00','#FF0000','#FFA500'];
         drawFixation();
         for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
         drawArrow(i*10, i*10, i*20, i*20, differentcolours[i]);
         } 
          resize(myCanvas);
      </script>              
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the size in pixels instead of percentage?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried it but it doesn't change anything for me (am using most recent Chrome to test).

Comment: Just to make sure, is [this](https://i.imgur.com/Fsz2yai.png) the result you get?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I get.

Comment: You're sending the string `myCanvas` in the function `resize` as the id but in the function you try to use it as if it was the element.

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I did that after just trying to directly implement myCanvas in the function and then calling resize() without input. Didn't work either. But even as object it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too draw at "fullscreen" (means viewport size here) is pretty easy:

```
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
```

this code seems to work for me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <style>
         * { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
         body, html { height:100%; }
         #myCanvas {
         position:absolute;
         }
      </style>
      <script>

         function drawFixation() {

         var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
         var centerX = c.width / 2;
         var centerY = c.height / 2;  
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
         ctx.moveTo(centerX-5,centerY);
         ctx.lineTo(centerX+5,centerY);
         ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY+5);
         ctx.lineTo(centerX,centerY-5);
         ctx.fillStyle ="#FFFFFF"
         ctx.lineWidth = 2;
         ctx.stroke();
         }


         function drawArrow(fromx, fromy, tox, toy, colourarrow){
             //variables to be used when creating the arrow
             var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
             var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
             var headlen = 3;

             var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);

             //starting path of the arrow from the start square to the end square and drawing the stroke
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
             ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
             ctx.strokeStyle = colourarrow;
             ctx.lineWidth = 5;
             ctx.stroke();

             //starting a new path from the head of the arrow to one of the sides of the point
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(tox, toy);
             ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));

             //path from the side point of the arrow, to the other side point
             ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/7));

             //path from the side point back to the tip of the arrow, and then again to the opposite side point
             ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
             ctx.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/7),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/7));

             //draws the paths created above
             ctx.strokeStyle = colourarrow;
             ctx.lineWidth = 5;
             ctx.stroke();
             ctx.fillStyle = colourarrow
             ctx.fill();
         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor='black'>
      <canvas  id="myCanvas" oncl></canvas>
      <script>
         var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         canvas.width = innerWidth;
         canvas.height = innerHeight;
         var differentcolours = ['#FFA500','#FFFF00','#FF0000','#FFA500'];
         drawFixation();
         for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
         drawArrow(i*10, i*10, i*20, i*20, differentcolours[i]);
         } 
      </script>              
   </body>
</html>
```

the snippet may not update here when expanding to fullscreen, so please try in an extra file...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly what I did in the first place. But it gives me very low resolution canvas. You can basically see a bunch of pixels but no sharp arrow as desired.

Comment: do you want to draw at full screen size or do you want to draw with low resolution but enlarge it to sharp and big pixels?

Comment: I want to draw at full screen but with high resolution. The method that I found draws the canvas and resizes it so it still keeps a reasonable resolution. But I must be doing something wrong as it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but this still gives me a fullscreen with very blocky and degraded arrows and cross. Here is a picture example of what I would like to get (don't worry about dimensions and colour, it's just for showing the idea): https://ibb.co/mwMaC6

Comment: did you remove the resize function and put my code before you draw on the canvas? please also remove the css from the canvas when testing. I'll try it myself meanwhile ...

Comment: posted my code and it uses the whole viewport. sure you need to make your functions draw bigger shapes if they're too small but they got clean edges now.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks for your patience and efforts, now works perfectly fine!